# Flutter - How to get a text field with HTML tag for the end users as input

Tags: android, flutter, dart, text

I have a **Flutter** Mobile App where the user can insert their data on text field.
I'd like give to the users the possibility to use **HTML tag** to compose their "cool" description (bold text, italic, etc..).

Can I do something like this for the user? (see attached image)

[image]

Comment: try this https://pub.dev/packages/html_editor_enhanced

Comment: or this: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_quill

Answer (score 2):

```
html_editor_enhanced: ^2.5.0
```

check it

```
import 'package:html_editor/html_editor.dart';
HtmlEditorController controller = HtmlEditorController();

@override Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return HtmlEditor(
controller: controller,
 htmlEditorOptions: HtmlEditorOptions(
  hint: "Your text here...",
 ), 
 otherOptions: OtherOptions(
);
```